# How to create dynamic routing in phalcon?

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have read the documentation of phalcon routing and cannot find the one like i needed.

```
/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/controllerName/actionName/{param4}
```

Help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html):

> /:params  (/.*)*  Matches a list of optional words separated by slashes. Only use this placeholder at the end of a route

In other hands you could rewrite their positions through `apache`/`.htaccess`.